# Failover cluster using powershell on windows 2008 sp1

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am not able to import-module failovercluster. Is there something that i need to do ?

i) its a x86 windows 2008 sp1 setup 
ii) has powershell 2.0 installed. 
iv) failover manager gui is accessible and functioning.

am i missing some important step?

Comment: [Solution]                                                        Import-module Failoverclusters does not workin x86 environments

Answer (score 1):

You need to type Import-Module failoverclusters and this only works in a x64 environment. I had the same problem trying to use this in Sapien Powershell studio, but it worked in powershell_ise, in some script editors you can change between 32bit and 64bit to test scripts.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a typo? The module name is `FailoverClusters` (note the trailing "s").